# Button's image becoming longer in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have strange problem with button's size in table view. I have table view with 4 cells. Every cell's size is This is a third of the screen size (minus navigation bar).
[Top and button of table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7HIS.jpg)

If I scroll down and click on fourth button (second, third, it doesn't matter because first button won't be visible) I will move to other VC. Then If I move to iOS Home Screen, and launch my app again and return to Table View I will see that table view is not fully scrolled down. It's not biggest problem because If I scroll up to the top of table view I will see that first button is much longer. How to resolve it? I've added constraints. 
[Issue with table view and normal table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbWwi.jpg)

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // get the height for the current view
    let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height

    // since we want 3 rows to appear at a time, simply divide the viewHeight by 3
    return viewHeight / 3
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // if the steps are selected, use those cell identifiers and configure them
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1") as! ButtonTableViewCell
        cell.buttonVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2") as! ButtonTableViewCell

        cell.buttonVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell3") as! ButtonTableViewCell


        cell.buttonVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell4") as! ButtonTableViewCell

        cell.buttonVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are used different identifier ?

Comment: Every button is linked with specific VC

Comment: yes but you can do that using single cell instead of multiple .. you need to set condition on its selector method .

Comment: and what you want exactly ... i cant understand your question .

Comment: First button becoming longer. Height is bigger. It's not good

Comment: only first button ? and when this occurs ?

Comment: Only first. It happens when I scroll down (first buton becoming unvisible) and tapping on second, third or four button. Then I'm going to Home Screen and returning to app. Then I'm scrolling up and see that first button's height is bigger

Comment: which background color for first button ?

Comment: My first button is dark blue

Comment: then set in first condition ...it is not present in first condition .

Comment: You're right. I deleted the code about background color

Comment: then check now ? what happen ?

Comment: The code was in my program always. I just copied it incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved with changing viewHeight

```
let viewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! - UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

Answer (score 0):

You need get height of TableView instead of self.view height

```
let viewHeight = tableView.frame.size.height
```

Comment: Well I have answered on my own questions and resolved my problem